# Copy data range and add to end of table

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement, copy-paste, listobject

I am trying to copy the data in Table11 (varies in number of rows) and insert it as values at the end of another table.

Depending on the value of Begin!G9 (either 001.001, 001.002) it will either get pasted in sheet '001.001' or '001.002'

'001.001' has 'Table 5'
'001.002' has 'Table 6'

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub Finalize()

    'Copy data in Item table to the appropriate page
    If Sheets("Begin").Range("G9") = "001.001" Then
        'Insert New Row
        Sheets("001.001").Select
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table5").ListRows.Add (1)

        'Copy and Paste from Begin to first row
        Worksheets("Begin").Range("G9:I9").Copy Worksheets("demo").Range("A2:C2")

    ElseIf Sheets("Begin").Range("G9") = "001.002" Then
        Sheets("001.002").Select
        Selection.ListObject.ListRows.Add AlwaysInsert:=True
        Worksheets("Begin").ListObjects("Table11").DataBodyRange.Copy Worksheets("001.002").ListObjects("Table6").ListRow.Add AlwaysInsert:=True

    End If

    Sheets("Begin").Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are my assumptions:

- On sheet Begin, you have a listobject starting in cell G8. It has one row.
- You have two other sheets named 001.001 and 001.002.
- Cell G9 (the first cell in the first row of the listobject on sheet Begin) will contain one of those sheet names.
- The listobjects on the two sheets have the same number of columns as the one on Begin

Here's some commented code

```
Sub CopyTable()

    Dim loSource As ListObject
    Dim loDest As ListObject

    'Get a reference to the table you want to copy
    Set loSource = Sheets("Begin").ListObjects(1)
    'Get a reference to the destination table
    Set loDest = Sheets(loSource.ListRows(1).Range.Cells(1).Value).ListObjects(1)

    'Copy the source to a new row
    loSource.DataBodyRange.Copy loDest.ListRows.Add.Range

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you! I had to change the reference for the loDest to another cell outside of the List Object, but it works perfectly!